# ¿Cómo reiniciar quiz después de completarlo?

Tags: javascript

Me encuentro haciendo mi quiz y lo que pasa es que quiero lograr que cuando llegue al cuadro de resultado donde aparece el puntaje, le de al botón de "Play Again" y me vuelva a reiniciar el quiz, que me lo mande a la primera página que apareció al principio.

Si lo prueban, de hecho, se va a la principal y me va a las preguntas luego, pero al momento de entrar a las preguntas la imagen no se quita y los botones están deshabilitados. Quiero que se me vuelva a poner como si hubiera recargado la página.

Éste es mi código:

```js
//array of Html fills
let fill = [{
    "title": "QUESTION 1",
    "question": "It is considered that the first high-level language was?",
    "option1": "Ada",
    "option2": "C",
    "option3": "Fortran",
    "option4": "Java",
    "answer": "3"
}, {
    "title": "QUESTION 2",
    "question": "if, else, for and while are?",
    "option1": "Data access functions",
    "option2": "Type of data",
    "option3": "Control statements",
    "option4": "all of the above",
    "answer": "3"
}, {
    "title": "QUESTION 3",
    "question": "The number 1010 in binary is represented in decimal as?",
    "option1": "8",
    "option2": "65",
    "option3": "97",
    "option4": "None of the above",
    "answer": "4"
}, {
    "title": "QUESTION 4",
    "question": "int, char, float, string y boolean are?",
    "option1": "Control statements",
    "option2": "Type of data",
    "option3": "Data acess functions",
    "option4": "Data access instructions",
    "answer": "2"
}, {
    "title": "QUESTION 5",
    "question": "What does EOF mean?",
    "option1": "Empty or full",
    "option2": "End of file",
    "option3": "End of loop",
    "option4": "None of the above",
    "answer": "2"
}]
//images wrong or correct
let imageCorrect = document.getElementById("correct");
let imageWrong = document.getElementById("wrong");
//variables general
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
let first = document.getElementById("first");
let contenedor = document.getElementsByClassName("contenedor")[0];
let question = document.getElementsByClassName("question")[0];
let title = document.getElementById("title");
let paragraph = document.getElementById("redact");
let option1 = document.getElementById("option1");
let option2 = document.getElementById("option2");
let option3 = document.getElementById("option3");
let option4 = document.getElementById("option4");
let message = document.getElementById("message");
let button = document.getElementById("start");
let check = document.getElementById("check");
let next = document.getElementById("next");
 let result = document.getElementById("result");
let input = document.querySelectorAll('.inputs input[type="radio"]');
let again = document.getElementById("again")
// points and question variables
let actualQuestion = 0;
let points = 0;
let numQuestions = fill.length;
// init page
body.addEventListener('load', start(), false);

function start() {

    question.style.display = 'none';

    // listener button
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
     
        first.style.display = 'none';
        contenedor.style.background = '#FFA54F';
        question.style.display = 'block';
        next.disabled = true;
    });
}
// fill html 
function arrays(index) {
    let quest = fill[index];
    title.textContent = quest.title;
    paragraph.textContent = quest.question;
    option1.textContent = quest.option1;
    option2.textContent = quest.option2;
    option3.textContent = quest.option3;
    option4.textContent = quest.option4;
    message.style.display = 'none';
}
// check answer
function nextQuestion() {
    let choose = document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked');
    if (!choose) {
        message.style.display = 'block';
        message.textContent = "Please answer the question";
        message.style.marginTop = "20px";
        message.style.fontSize = "0.7em";
    } else {
        let value = choose.value;
        if (fill[actualQuestion].answer == value) {
            imageCorrect.style.display = "block";
            disabledInputs()
            points += 20;
        } else {
            imageWrong.style.display = 'block';
            disabledInputs()
        }
        if ((choose.checked)) {
            message.style.display = "none";
            next.disabled = false;
            check.disabled = true;
        }
        choose.checked = false;
        actualQuestion++;
        if (actualQuestion === numQuestions) {
            next.textContent = "Result";
        }
    }
}
//button next
next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (actualQuestion === numQuestions) {
       
        let score = document.getElementById("score");
        question.style.display = 'none';
        contenedor.style.background = "#FFAE75";
        result.style.display = "block";
        score.textContent = "Your score " + points;
    } else {
        next.disabled = true;
        check.disabled =false;
        imageWrong.style.display = "none";
        imageCorrect.style.display = "none";
        activeInputs()
        arrays(actualQuestion);
    }
})
//disabled buttons after answer
function disabledInputs() {
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        input[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
//active next question
function activeInputs() {
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        input[i].disabled = false;
    }
}
// check the answer
check.addEventListener('click', nextQuestion)
again.addEventListener('click',function(){

   result.style.display="none";
   first.style.display="block";
   actualQuestion=0;
    points = 0;



   arrays(actualQuestion)


});

arrays(actualQuestion);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rock+Salt|VT323');

body{

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#A4BFAA,#FFD6CA)
  
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E5A46A, grey);
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}
h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.contenedor {
    font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
    display: block;
    border: 4px solid black;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: #FF7163;
    padding: 40px;
    outline: 4px dotted black;
    outline-offset: 10px;
}
.introduction {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
button {
    width: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.question, #score {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.inputs {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
label {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
input[type='radio'] {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
input[type='radio']:after {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: -3px;
    left: -1px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #d1d3d1;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
input[type='radio']:checked:after {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: -2px;
    left: -1px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #4F8ABF;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
.image {
    max-width: 80px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.correct, .wrong, .result {
    display: none;
}
p .message {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: none;
}
@media(max-width: 475px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 1.8em;
    }
    h3 {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .introduction {
        font-size: 1em;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 12px;
    }
    button {
        width: 60px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .redact {
        font-size: .7em;
        line-height: 12px;
    }
    .inputs {
        font-size: .6em;
        width: 100px;
    }
    input[type='radio'] {
        margin-left: 25px;
    }
    p .message {
        font-size: .5em;
    }
    .image {
        max-width: 50px;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
 <title>Quiz Game</title>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <header class="row">
   <div class="col">
    <h1>Quiz Game</h1>
   </div>
  </header><!-- /header -->
  <main class="row contenedor p-3 ">
   <div class="col">
    <div class="row question">
     <div class="col-12">
      <h3 id="title"></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12">
      <p class="redact" id="redact"></p>
     </div>
     <div class="row p-0">
      <div class=" col-xs-11 col-8  p-0 inputs">
       <input id="answer1" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="1"><label class="select" for="answer1"><span id="option1"></span></label><br>
       <input id="answer2" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="2"><label class="select" for="answer2"><span id="option2"></span></label><br>
       <input id="answer3" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="3"><label class="select" for="answer3"><span id="option3"></span></label><br>
       <input id="answer4" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="4"><label class="select" for="answer4"><span id="option4"></span></label>
      </div>
      <div class=" col-4 col-xs-1 p-0 images"><img alt="correct" class="image correct" id="correct" src ="https://www.matrixinternet.ie/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Check-300x300.png"> <img alt="correct" class="image wrong" id="wrong" src="https://i2.wp.com/mettagiri.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/cancel-1174809_1280.png?fit=728%2C728&ssl=1"></div>
      <div class="col-12">
       <p id="message" class="message"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
       <button class=" btn btn-danger mt-4 check" id="check">Check!</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
       <button class=" btn btn-outline-dark mt-4  next" id="next" class="result">Next!</button>
      </div>
      
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col result" id="result">
       
                            <h2>Thanks For play</h2> 
                            <p id="score" class="mb-3"></p>

                            <button class=" btn btn-success mt-4  next" id="again" class="result">Play Again!</button>

      </div>
    <div id="first" class="row">
     <div class="col">
     <h2>Welcome to Quiz Game</h2>
     <p class="introduction">The game consists of answering the questions that will appear as you answer, once you have finished answering, you will get your results</p>
     <h3>ARE YOU READY?</h3><button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" id="start">Start!</button>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </main>
 </div>
 <script src="js/index.js">
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo tienes básicamente hecho, apenas te falta un pequeño cambio. Ya tienes el código que "resetea" el formulario de preguntas (dentro de un `else` en el controlador del evento `click` para el botón "next"):

```
next.disabled = true;
check.disabled =false;
imageWrong.style.display = "none";
imageCorrect.style.display = "none";
activeInputs();
```

El problema es que no lo estás llamando cuando se le da a empezar de nuevo porque en ese momento el valor de `actualQuestion` es el mismo que el número de preguntas y por eso siempre entra en la condición del `if` y no en la del `else`.

Teniendo en cuenta que sólo se entra en el `if` cuando el quiz ha terminado, una solución rápida sería quitar el `else` y hacer que su código se ejecute siempre cuando se llega a ese punto, y dentro del `if` indicar que el número de pregunta es igual a 0 (cero).

El código con esos dos cambios:

```js
//array of Html fills
let fill = [{
    "title": "QUESTION 1",
    "question": "It is considered that the first high-level language was?",
    "option1": "Ada",
    "option2": "C",
    "option3": "Fortran",
    "option4": "Java",
    "answer": "3"
}, {
    "title": "QUESTION 2",
    "question": "if, else, for and while are?",
    "option1": "Data access functions",
    "option2": "Type of data",
    "option3": "Control statements",
    "option4": "all of the above",
    "answer": "3"
}, {
    "title": "QUESTION 3",
    "question": "The number 1010 in binary is represented in decimal as?",
    "option1": "8",
    "option2": "65",
    "option3": "97",
    "option4": "None of the above",
    "answer": "4"
}, {
    "title": "QUESTION 4",
    "question": "int, char, float, string y boolean are?",
    "option1": "Control statements",
    "option2": "Type of data",
    "option3": "Data acess functions",
    "option4": "Data access instructions",
    "answer": "2"
}, {
    "title": "QUESTION 5",
    "question": "What does EOF mean?",
    "option1": "Empty or full",
    "option2": "End of file",
    "option3": "End of loop",
    "option4": "None of the above",
    "answer": "2"
}]
//images wrong or correct
let imageCorrect = document.getElementById("correct");
let imageWrong = document.getElementById("wrong");
//variables general
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
let first = document.getElementById("first");
let contenedor = document.getElementsByClassName("contenedor")[0];
let question = document.getElementsByClassName("question")[0];
let title = document.getElementById("title");
let paragraph = document.getElementById("redact");
let option1 = document.getElementById("option1");
let option2 = document.getElementById("option2");
let option3 = document.getElementById("option3");
let option4 = document.getElementById("option4");
let message = document.getElementById("message");
let button = document.getElementById("start");
let check = document.getElementById("check");
let next = document.getElementById("next");
 let result = document.getElementById("result");
let input = document.querySelectorAll('.inputs input[type="radio"]');
let again = document.getElementById("again")
// points and question variables
let actualQuestion = 0;
let points = 0;
let numQuestions = fill.length;
// init page
body.addEventListener('load', start(), false);

function start() {

    question.style.display = 'none';

    // listener button
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
     
        first.style.display = 'none';
        contenedor.style.background = '#FFA54F';
        question.style.display = 'block';
        next.disabled = true;
    });
}
// fill html 
function arrays(index) {
    let quest = fill[index];
    title.textContent = quest.title;
    paragraph.textContent = quest.question;
    option1.textContent = quest.option1;
    option2.textContent = quest.option2;
    option3.textContent = quest.option3;
    option4.textContent = quest.option4;
    message.style.display = 'none';
}
// check answer
function nextQuestion() {
    let choose = document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked');
    if (!choose) {
        message.style.display = 'block';
        message.textContent = "Please answer the question";
        message.style.marginTop = "20px";
        message.style.fontSize = "0.7em";
    } else {
        let value = choose.value;
        if (fill[actualQuestion].answer == value) {
            imageCorrect.style.display = "block";
            disabledInputs()
            points += 20;
        } else {
            imageWrong.style.display = 'block';
            disabledInputs()
        }
        if ((choose.checked)) {
            message.style.display = "none";
            next.disabled = false;
            check.disabled = true;
        }
        choose.checked = false;
        actualQuestion++;
        if (actualQuestion === numQuestions) {
            next.textContent = "Result";
        }
    }
}
//button next
next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (actualQuestion === numQuestions) {
       
        let score = document.getElementById("score");
        question.style.display = 'none';
        contenedor.style.background = "#FFAE75";
        result.style.display = "block";
        score.textContent = "Your score " + points;
        
        // resetear el número de pregunta a 0
        actualQuestion = 0;
    }
    
    // quitamos el else para que esta parte se ejecute siempre
    next.disabled = true;
    check.disabled =false;
    imageWrong.style.display = "none";
    imageCorrect.style.display = "none";
    activeInputs()
    arrays(actualQuestion);

})
//disabled buttons after answer
function disabledInputs() {
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        input[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
//active next question
function activeInputs() {
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        input[i].disabled = false;
    }
}
// check the answer
check.addEventListener('click', nextQuestion)
again.addEventListener('click',function(){

   result.style.display="none";
   first.style.display="block";
   actualQuestion=0;
    points = 0;



   arrays(actualQuestion)


});

arrays(actualQuestion);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rock+Salt|VT323');

body{

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#A4BFAA,#FFD6CA)
  
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E5A46A, grey);
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}
h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.contenedor {
    font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
    display: block;
    border: 4px solid black;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: #FF7163;
    padding: 40px;
    outline: 4px dotted black;
    outline-offset: 10px;
}
.introduction {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
button {
    width: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.question, #score {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.inputs {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
label {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
input[type='radio'] {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
input[type='radio']:after {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: -3px;
    left: -1px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #d1d3d1;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
input[type='radio']:checked:after {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: -2px;
    left: -1px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #4F8ABF;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
.image {
    max-width: 80px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.correct, .wrong, .result {
    display: none;
}
p .message {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: none;
}
@media(max-width: 475px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 1.8em;
    }
    h3 {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .introduction {
        font-size: 1em;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 12px;
    }
    button {
        width: 60px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .redact {
        font-size: .7em;
        line-height: 12px;
    }
    .inputs {
        font-size: .6em;
        width: 100px;
    }
    input[type='radio'] {
        margin-left: 25px;
    }
    p .message {
        font-size: .5em;
    }
    .image {
        max-width: 50px;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
 <title>Quiz Game</title>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <header class="row">
   <div class="col">
    <h1>Quiz Game</h1>
   </div>
  </header><!-- /header -->
  <main class="row contenedor p-3 ">
   <div class="col">
    <div class="row question">
     <div class="col-12">
      <h3 id="title"></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12">
      <p class="redact" id="redact"></p>
     </div>
     <div class="row p-0">
      <div class=" col-xs-11 col-8  p-0 inputs">
       <input id="answer1" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="1"><label class="select" for="answer1"><span id="option1"></span></label><br>
       <input id="answer2" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="2"><label class="select" for="answer2"><span id="option2"></span></label><br>
       <input id="answer3" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="3"><label class="select" for="answer3"><span id="option3"></span></label><br>
       <input id="answer4" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="4"><label class="select" for="answer4"><span id="option4"></span></label>
      </div>
      <div class=" col-4 col-xs-1 p-0 images"><img alt="correct" class="image correct" id="correct" src ="https://www.matrixinternet.ie/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Check-300x300.png"> <img alt="correct" class="image wrong" id="wrong" src="https://i2.wp.com/mettagiri.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/cancel-1174809_1280.png?fit=728%2C728&ssl=1"></div>
      <div class="col-12">
       <p id="message" class="message"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
       <button class=" btn btn-danger mt-4 check" id="check">Check!</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
       <button class=" btn btn-outline-dark mt-4  next" id="next" class="result">Next!</button>
      </div>
      
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col result" id="result">
       
                            <h2>Thanks For play</h2> 
                            <p id="score" class="mb-3"></p>

                            <button class=" btn btn-success mt-4  next" id="again" class="result">Play Again!</button>

      </div>
    <div id="first" class="row">
     <div class="col">
     <h2>Welcome to Quiz Game</h2>
     <p class="introduction">The game consists of answering the questions that will appear as you answer, once you have finished answering, you will get your results</p>
     <h3>ARE YOU READY?</h3><button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" id="start">Start!</button>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </main>
 </div>
 <script src="js/index.js">
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para reiniciar el cuestionario, hice una función denominada `reiniciar_entradas`. Esta función es llamada por `next` y `start`. Todo lo que había en el `else` de `next` lo pasé a esa función, y además cambié el texto de `next`. Al finalizar el juego, el texto cambia a `Result!`, pero nunca más vuelve a cambiar a `Next!`... Entonces la modificación que hice fue para que lo cambie otra vez al finalizar.

Para simplificar las cosas, quité todos los estilos y Bootstrap, pero si quieres, puedes agregarlo nuevamente. Hice una simplificación de todo el código, cambiando la estructura de la variable `fill`.

Cambié las imágenes porque eran demasiado grandes, pienso que reduciría el tiempo de carga del sitio (sería más responsivo), y otra cosa que noté fue que en las dos imágenes dice `alt="correct"`, cuando una debería ser `correct` y otra `wrong`.

Al quitar Bootstrap y reducir un poco los estilos, no quedó tan elegante, pero por lo menos funciona... En el `input` de seleccionar la respuesta, también noté que se superpone con el botón original, así que supongo que tendría que ocultarlo, haciendo más grande el seleccionador, o de alguna otra manera.

Código:

```js
function arrays(index) {
  var quest = preguntas[index];
  title.textContent = "Pregunta "+(index+1);
  redact.textContent = quest.pregunta;
  for(var i in quest.opciones)
  {
    document.getElementById(
      "option"+(+i+1)
    ).textContent = quest.opciones[i];
  }
  message.style.display = 'none';
}
function reiniciar_entradas(){
    next.disabled = true;
    check.disabled =false;
    wrong.style.display = "none";
    correct.style.display = "none";
    activeInputs()
    arrays(actualQuestion);
}
function disabledInputs() {
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i].disabled = true;
  }
}
function activeInputs() {
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i].disabled = false;
  }
}

start.addEventListener('click', function() {
  first.style.display = 'none';
  question.style.display = "block";
  next.textContent = "Siguiente";
  reiniciar_entradas()
});
next.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (actualQuestion === numQuestions) {
    var score = document.getElementById("score");
    result.style.display = "block";
    question.style.display = "none";
    score.textContent = points;
  } else {
    reiniciar_entradas()
  }
})
check.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var choose = document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked');
  if (!choose) {
    message.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    var value = choose.value;
    if (preguntas[actualQuestion].respuesta == value) {
      correct.style.display = "block";
      disabledInputs()
      points += 20;
    } else {
      wrong.style.display = 'block';
      disabledInputs()
    }
    if ((choose.checked)) {
      message.style.display = "none";
      next.disabled = false;
      check.disabled = true;
    }
    choose.checked = false;
    actualQuestion++;
    if (actualQuestion === numQuestions) {
      next.textContent = "Resultado";
    }
  }
})
again.addEventListener('click',function(){
  result.style.display="none";
  first.style.display="block";
  actualQuestion=0;
  points = 0;
  arrays(actualQuestion)
});

var preguntas = [
  {respuesta:3,"pregunta":"¿Cuál es el primer lenguaje de alto nivel?",
    "opciones":["Ada","C","Fortran","Java"]},
  {respuesta:3,"pregunta":"¿Qué son if, else, for y while son?",
    "opciones":["Funciones","Tipos de datos","Sentencias de control","Todos"]},
  {respuesta:4,"pregunta":"¿Cuánto es 1010 de binario?",
    "opciones":["8","65","97","Ninguno"]},
  {respuesta:2,"pregunta":"int, char, float, string y boolean son...",
    "opciones":["Sentencias","Tipos de datos","Funciones","Instrucciones"]},
  {respuesta:2,"pregunta":"¿Qué es EOF?",
    "opciones":["Empty or full","End of file","End of find","Ninguno"]}
]
var general = {}
var input     = document.querySelectorAll('.inputs input[type="radio"]')
var contenedor= document.querySelector(".contenedor")
var question  = document.querySelector(".question")
var actualQuestion = 0;
var points = 0;
var numQuestions = preguntas.length;
arrays(actualQuestion);
```

```css
body{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#A4BFAA,#FFD6CA)
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E5A46A, grey);
}
h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.contenedor {
    font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background: #11BBFFAA;
}
h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
}
input[type='radio']:after {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #d1d3d1;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
}
input[type='radio']:checked:after {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #4F8ABF;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
}
.wrong, .correct, .result, .question{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <title>Quiz Game</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="row">
      <div class="col">
      </div>
    </header><!-- /header -->
    <main class="row contenedor p-3 ">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row question">
<button class="btn btn-danger mt-4 check" id="check">¡Comprobar!</button> <button class=" btn btn-outline-dark mt-4  next" id="next" class="result">¡Siguiente!</button>
<p id="message" class="message">Debes responder la pregunta para continuar.</p>
<center>
<img alt="correct" class="correct" id="correct" src ="http://submarinobursatil.com/imagenes/landings/icon-3-llaves.png" />
<img alt="wrong" class="wrong" id="wrong" src="http://www.fmatlanticselva.com.ar/img/admin/cruz.png" /></center>
          <div class="col-12">
            <h3 id="title"></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12">
            <p class="redact" id="redact"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="row p-0">
            <div class=" col-xs-11 col-8  p-0 inputs">
              <input id="answer1" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="1"><label class="select" for="answer1"><span id="option1"></span></label>
              <input id="answer2" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="2"><label class="select" for="answer2"><span id="option2"></span></label><br/>
              <input id="answer3" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="3"><label class="select" for="answer3"><span id="option3"></span></label>
              <input id="answer4" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="4"><label class="select" for="answer4"><span id="option4"></span></label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col result" id="result">
    <h2>Gracias por jugar</h2> 
    <p class="mb-3">Tu puntaje es: <a id="score"></a></p>
    <button class="btn btn-success mt-4  next" id="again" class="result">¡Jugar denuevo!</button>
        </div>
        <div id="first" class="row">
          <div class="col">
          <p class="introduction">El juego consiste en responder las preguntas que aparecen como opciones, usted debe obtener buenos resultados.</p>
          <h3>¿Estás listo?</h3><button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" id="start">¡Comenzar!</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
 </div>
  </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

para reiniciar utiliza: `window.location = '/';`
Donde `'/'` es la página de inicio (home ó index). Si es para otra: `'/otrapagina'`.

En el último botón agrega una funcion javascript:

```
<button class=" btn btn-success mt-4  next" id="again" class="result" onclick="reiniciar()">Play Again!</button>
```

y el script sería:

```
<script>  
function reiniciar() {                          
window.location = '/';             
}        
</script>
```

Comment: El autor pidió reiniciar el formulario, no cargar toda la página de nuevo!